# How to convert this Python for loop into a list comprehension?

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert this for loop into a list comprehension. This for loop iterates through a data frame to find every row where the entry for column `'TL'` includes "J" and column `'Ink' = 0` and delete the whole row:

```
for r in df.T:
    if 'J' in df.loc[r,'TL'] and df.loc[r,'Ink'] == 0:
        df.drop(r)
    else:
        continue
```

I've tried this

```
df_clean = [
    df.drop(r) for r in df.T if 'J' in df.loc[r,'TL'] and df.loc[r,'Ink'] == 0
]
```

I get an error stating

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Have you tried anything? Give it a shot if you haven't, then come back if you need help. If you have, show us.

Comment: Are you really sure you want a list comprehension? Even assuming you could get it to work, it looks like you will wind up with a list of DataFrame objects, one for each `r` in `df.T`. What is wrong with a `for` loop, anyway?

Comment: I want to use a list comprehension because the data sets I'm working with are huge, and a `for` loop would take forever to run.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df[~(df.TL.str.contains('J') & df.Ink.eq(0))]
```

Comment: That seemed to work! I need to double check the data file since its huge (700,000 rows) but it looks good. Thank you!